# How to store and play mp3 on mobile safari?

Tags: html, audio, mobile-safari

I have a mp3 audio file and I want to store it locally in safari cache (localstorage, especifying in manifest, etc) and then play it back offline (airplane mode)

How is it possible?

Comment: You could accomplish almost the same result with e-mail

Answer (score 0):

Two words, Not possible. (At least with a web app)